# MySQL: Cross match records from two different columns

Tags: mysql, sql

I got table Followers which looks like this:

```
| id | follower_id | user_id |
| 1  | user1       | user2   |
| 2  | user2       | user3   |
| 3  | user2       | user1   |
| 4  | user4       | user3   |
| 5  | user3       | user2   |
```

I need to count instances when two users are following each other, in this case result should be 2, because user1 and user2, user2 and user3 is following each other.

I tried all sorts of combinations of LEFT JOIN, SELECT COUNT() FROM table WHERE field IN(), but I think I'm missing something... I feel though that I'm close to the goal with this query

```
SELECT
    u.id,
    u.name,
    u.img,
    ifnull((follower_id and user_id),0) as `match`
FROM table_users u
LEFT JOIN (select user_id from table_followers where follower_id = 14)   followers on u.id = followers.user_id
LEFT JOIN (select follower_id from table_followers where user_id = 14) following on u.id = following.follower_id
WHERE u.id = 14 and (follower_id or user_id)
```

With this query I'm trying to figure out how many followers user_id_14 has.

Is it possible to achieve this with pure MySQL, or I should go around this with PHP loops?

This is making a headache to me for three hours and I can't find solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT
    CONVERT(COUNT(*)/2, UNSIGNED) as counter
FROM followers u
INNER JOIN (
    select 
      user_id,
      follower_id
    from followers 
) as f 
on u.user_id = f.follower_id
WHERE u.follower_id = f.user_id
```

Answer (score 1):

This may help you..

```
Select count(*) 
From followers f1 
    joins followers f2 ON f1.follower_id = f2.user_id 
                      and f1.user_id= f2.followerid;
```

Comment: You know, this actually works. It returns doubled results, but I can divide the number by two. Thanks